# Here in this code shouldn't be there be two times harishshima printed?

Tags: c

Here in this code shouldn't be there be two times harishshima printed?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
    {
        char s3[100] ;
        char s1[]=" harish";
        char s2[]="shima";
        puts (strcat(s1,s2)); // concating two strings
        strcpy(s3,strcat(s1,s2));
        puts (s3);
    }
```

Comment: Your code is full of undefined behaviour.  The results of undefined behaviour are undefined — you have no right to expect any specific result.

Comment: Try changing `char s1[]=" harish";` to `char s1[20]=" harish";`.

Comment: Remember, `strcat` does *not* construct a brand-new string which is the concatenation of `s1` and `s2`.  What it does it tack `s2` on to the end of `s1`, in-place.  So `s1` must be modifiable and it must have enough extra space allocated to additionally hold `s2`.

Answer (score 0):

```c
puts (strcat(s1,s2));
```

This line copies s2 to the end of s1. It will overwrite whatever data happens to be there, so you must make sure you give it enough space (in this case at least 7 + 5 + 1 = 13 characters).

```c
char s1[13] = " harish";
```

Because s2 is relatively short, you don't overwrite anything that impacts your program, but here is what happened when I set `char s2[] = "shimabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`:

```c
 harishshimabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 harishshimabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzhim harishshimabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzhim harishshimabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzhim harishshimabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzhim harishshimabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzhim harishshimabcdefghijklmnopqrst
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

```c
strcpy(s3,strcat(s1,s2));
```

This line again copies s2 to the end of s1, but remember that s1 now contains  `harishshima` after the previous `strcat`. The `strcpy` then copies s1 into s3, so s3 will contain  `harishshimashima`.